# Application drastically slows down after sql migration

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

Im using a powerbuilder app written in version 12.5 and is now currently using a MSSql 2016. In the past this application is using MSSql 2008 and there is no speed issue. Recently this month, we migrated the database from MSSql 2008 directly to MSSql 2016 and this migration greatly affected the speed of the application.

Whenever the application makes a data query on the server it took more than 5 second in which the users is having a hard time. Even the simple search, filter and edit took a lot of time.

This scenario never happened when the server was in mssql2008...

My question is, does the mssql 2016 has some issues or changes the database in some manner? before the migration, the mssql 2016 reports a coalescence error in some table. Does this affects the usual operation of the system? Does the index from 2008 server will be affected when it was migrated? do i need to create a new set of table indexes?

I dont know what kind of solution i can implement and im contacting the server administrators.

Just some more information: The server and the application is found on the same building. The server being in the 3rd floor while the application is run from 9th to 16th. Powerbuilder that im using is version 12.5 build 2511. the data is about 3 million rows.

Comment: There was a huge change to the cardinality between SQl Server 2008 and 2016. I suspect that some of the queries you have perform poorly on the new one (the new one *tends* the run better on well written queries, however, poorly written queries will perform worse). You could try changing the compatibility of the database down to 110 (2012) and see how it runs. If it runs fast again, it's the cardinality. This'll likely mean you need to review your query and performance tune it. If you share the query, I'm sure the volunteers here will be happy to help.

Comment: Update all statistics if you haven't done so post migration. Not saying this will fix it but it should be a post migration task pretty much always.

Comment: Rather than change the database compatibility level, try switching to the legacy cardinality estimator with `USE YourDatabase;ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = ON`

Comment: It's September 5 now and the problem seems gone when the System administrators increase the number of cores the machine uses from 2 to 4 now and increased the ram to 40gb. But there are times that the server will have 100% CPU usage even in non-peak hours (7-9 am) I am still observing the server and the end client. But the increase in cores and memory did help to fasten the process but not the original performance compare to the performance prior to migration. Thank you all for the answers!